# Counting words, characters and lines

Tags: java

The method is to return an array counting the number of lines, words and characters in a document. After running it through a test file I am still receiving some errors.

```
public static int[] wc(Reader in) throws IOException {

    int data = in.read();       
    int charcounter = 0;
    int linecounter = 0;
    int wordcounter = 0; 
    boolean previouswhitespace = false; 

    while (data != -1){

        if (((char) data == '\n')){
            linecounter++; 
        }
        if (!(Character.isWhitespace((char) data))){
            charcounter++;
                if ((previouswhitespace == true) || (wordcounter == 0)){
                    previouswhitespace = false; 
                    wordcounter++; 
                }
        }
        else if ((Character.isWhitespace((char) data))){
            previouswhitespace = true; 
        }
        data = in.read(); 
    }
    int[] array = {linecounter, wordcounter, charcounter};      
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `'\n'` is not a platform-independent line break

Comment: what errors? post it on the question.

Comment: also, I'm pretty sure that casting int data to char is not the correct way to perform a character decoding operation. there are many possible readers and file streams which would be better for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
//To choose the file
     JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String file_path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    char[] c;
    String [] words;
    int charCounter = 0 ,wordsCounter = 0, lineCounter = 0;
    //try and catch for the BufferedReader
    try{
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_path));
        while( (line = reader.readLine()) !=null){


         c = line.replace(" ","").toCharArray();
         charCounter+=c.length;    
         words = line.split(" ");
         wordsCounter+=words.length;
         lineCounter++;
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        // Handle the Exception
    }

   int array[] = {charCounter , wordsCounter, lineCounter};
```

Hope this is helping you!

Comment: Note: since BufferedReader doesn't return the linebreaks you will have no way of counting them here. a) they could be one or two characters b) if one appears directly before EOF it will be omitted.